# Alignments on IA32 machine x86

Tags: x86, alignment

[image]

Why are the offsets: 0 4 8 16 and 24? int = 4 bytes, double = 8 bytes. Why are there x's on the markings? How do you know when to use x's?

How does the other 2 structs and union offsets work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a data type generally aligns to its size. So a four-byte integer will usually begin on a multiple of four bytes. This is not always necessary but it's often an efficiency method. It *is* necessary in some architectures in that they'll actually crash (raise some sort of error) if you try to access misaligned data.

The reason you have the `x` characters is because they're the padding required to align the following data item.